# relations among the bounds of $f(x),f'(x),f''(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Is there any relations among the bounds of $f(x),f'(x),f''(x)$ ?

say $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function with $|f(x)|\le 1,|f''(x)|\le 2$ what bound I can  say about $|f'(x)|\le ?$

Thank you for any hints or discussion.

Comment: That $|f'(x)|\leqslant\sqrt2$ for every $x$. Now, what did you try?

Comment: This question is related to the Landau-Kolmogorov inequality.

Comment: I was trying to deduce something from Taylors formula

Comment: @did I thing you are wrong

Comment: @SenoreBunuel Nice. But this does not answer my question, does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $M_0,M_1,M_2$ denote the least upper bounds of $|f(x)|,|f'(x)|,|f''(x)|$ respectively.

If $h>0$, Taylor's theorem shows that 
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2h} \left[f(x+2h)-f(x) \right]-hf''(\xi) $$ for some $\xi \in(x,x+2h)$. Hence $$|f'(x)| \leq h M_2+\frac{M_0}{h} $$
We would like to choose the number $h$ which makes the RHS minimal, in order to find the optimal bound. It is easy to differentiate WRT $h$, and see that the minimum occurs when $h=\sqrt{\frac{M_0}{M_2}}$, so that $$|f'(x)| \leq2 \sqrt{M_0 M_2} $$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$. Taking the supremum we find $$|M_1| \leq2 \sqrt{M_0M_2}. $$

In our case, $M_0 \leq 1$ and $M_2 \leq 2$ so that $$|f'(x)| \leq2 \sqrt{2}$$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: Or without differentiation: $hM_2+\frac{M_0}h\ge 2\sqrt{M_0M_2}$ by AGM, with equality iff $hM_2=\frac{M_0}{h}$.

Comment: With a sine curve, we get $\sqrt{ M_0M_2}$ instead. But the result found is indeed sharp as can be seen from glueing parabolas in a wavelike pattern.